# Calculadora em JavaScript + HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho que fazer uma calculadora em JavaScript para a aula, e estou a deparar-me com vários erros. Eu queria fazer em que primeiro escreve-se o número 1 e sem seguida escolher qual operação fazer, depois da operação escolhida introduzir o segundo número, e no fim clicar no botão "Enviar" que irá mostrar o resultado num `alert`, mas estou a ver dificuldade para fazer o mesmo. Poderiam ajudar-me?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Aula</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style type="text/css">
      body{
         background: gray url(Image/mosaico.jpg) repeat;
      }
      </style>
      <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script>
      //alert("Ola mundo");
      function ola(x){
         var f=document.getElementById("frm");
         var txt = f.txtnome;
         txt.value = "Ola "+txt.value;
      }

      function soma() {
         //alert("1");
         var f=document.getElementById("frm");
         var n1=document.getElementById("n1").value;
         var n2=document.getElementById("n2").value;
         var soma = n1 + n2 ;
         alert(soma);
      }

      function subtracao() {
         var f=document.getElementById("frm");
         var n1=document.getElementById("n1").value;
         var n2=document.getElementById("n2").value;
         var soma = n1 - n2 ;
         alert(soma);
      } 

      function multiplicacao() {
         var f=document.getElementById("frm");
         var n1=document.getElementById("n1").value;
         var n2=document.getElementById("n2").value;
         var soma = n1 * n2 ;
         alert(soma);
      } 

      function divisao() {
         var f=document.getElementById("frm");
         var n1=document.getElementById("n1").value;
         var n2=document.getElementById("n2").value;
         var soma = n1 / n2 ;
         alert(soma);
      } 

      function mostrarresultados() {

      }

      function limpar(){
         //alert("1");
         var f=document.getElementById("frm");
         var n1 = f.n1;
         var n2 = f.n2;

         n1.value = "";
         n2.value = "";
      }
      </script>

   </head>
   <body>
   <form id="frm"  >
      <div id="container">
         <div id="topo"> 
            <h1>Aula de Web</h1>
         </div>

         <div id="menu">
         </div>

         <div id="left">
            <div class="bloco">
               <span>Nome:</span>
               <input type="text" name="txtnome" placeholder="Introduza o seu nome">
               <input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="ola('Ola')">
            </div>
            <div class="bloco1">
               <span>Introduza os numeros:</span><br>
               <input type="text" size="2" name="n1" placeholder="n1"><br>
               <input type="text" size="2"  name="n2" placeholder="n2"><br><br>
               <input type="button" value="+" onClick="soma()">
               <input type="button" value="-" onClick="subtracao('')">
               <input type="button" value="*" onClick="multiplicacao('')">
               <input type="button" value="/" onClick="divisao('')"><br><br>
               <input type="button" value="Limpar" onClick="limpar()"/>
               <input type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="ola('Ola')">
            </div>
         </div>

         <div id="right">
            <img id="mario1" src="Image/mario1.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img id="mario2" src="Image/mario2.jpg" alt=""/>      
         </div>

         <div id="bottom">

         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Teria que refazer todo o código, pois a sua calculadora já está toda montada.

Comment: o problema é que da maneira que montei nada esta a funcionar infelizmente :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como sua calculadora já está montada e não está funcional, vou sugerir estas alterações para fazê-la funcionar e simplificar seu código.

**1.** Crie apenas 1 função para fazer os cálculos, sem ter que fazer 1 função para cada operação matemática:

```
function calc(e){

   var operacao = e.value;

   var n1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
   var n2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);

   var calculo = eval(n1+operacao+n2);

   if(!isNaN(calculo)){
      alert(calculo);
   }

}
```

**2.** Adicione `onclick` em cada botão de operação matemática chamando a função acima:

```
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="calc(this)">
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="calc(this)">
<input type="button" value="*" onclick="calc(this)">
<input type="button" value="/" onclick="calc(this)">
```

No final, seu código seria este:

```js
function calc(e){
   
   var operacao = e.value;
   
   var n1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
   var n2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);
   
   var calculo = eval(n1+operacao+n2);

   if(!isNaN(calculo)){
      alert(calculo);
   }
  
}

function ola(x){
   var f=document.getElementById("frm");
   var txt = f.txtnome;
   txt.value = "Ola "+txt.value;
}

function limpar(){
   //alert("1");
   var f=document.getElementById("frm");
   var n1 = f.n1;
   var n2 = f.n2;
   n1.value = "";
   n2.value = "";
}
```

```html
<form id="frm"  >
   <div id="container">
      <div id="topo"> 
         <h1>Aula de Web</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
      </div>
      <div id="left">
         <div class="bloco">
            <span>Nome:</span>
            <input type="text" name="txtnome" placeholder="Introduza o seu nome">
            <input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="ola('Ola')">
         </div>
         <div class="bloco1">
            <span>Introduza os numeros:</span><br>
            <input type="text" size="2" id="n1" placeholder="n1"><br>
            <input type="text" size="2"  id="n2" placeholder="n2"><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="+" onClick="calc(this)">
            <input type="button" value="-" onClick="calc(this)">
            <input type="button" value="*" onClick="calc(this)">
            <input type="button" value="/" onClick="calc(this)">
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Limpar" onClick="limpar()"/>
            <input type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="ola('Ola')">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
         <img id="mario1" src="Image/mario1.jpg" alt=""/>
         <img id="mario2" src="Image/mario2.jpg" alt=""/>      
      </div>
      <div id="bottom">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ahhhh percebi, livrou-me de muito trabalho !

Answer (score 4):

```js
function writeNumber(elementId) {
  var outputValueTo = document.getElementById('field1');

  if (outputValueTo.value == '0' || outputValueTo.value == 'Syntax error') {
    outputValueTo.value = elementId.textContent;
  } else {

    outputValueTo.value += elementId.textContent;
  }
}

function cleartxt() {
  document.getElementById('field1').value = '0';
  document.getElementById('dec').disabled = false;
}

function setOperator(elementId) {
  var outputValueTo = document.getElementById('field1');
  if (outputValueTo.value == '0' || outputValueTo.value == 'Syntax error') {
    outputValueTo.value = '0';
  } else {
    outputValueTo.value += elementId.textContent;
    document.getElementById('dec').disabled = false;
  }
}

function setDecimal(elementId, status) {
  var outputValueTo = document.getElementById('field1');
  outputValueTo.value += elementId.textContent;
  document.getElementById('dec').disabled = status;
}

function calculate() {

  try {

    var field1txt = document.getElementById('field1');
    if (field1txt.value != '') {
      var calculateResult = eval(field1txt.value);
      field1txt.value = calculateResult;
    }
  } catch (err) {

    field1txt.value = 'Syntax error';

  }

}

function removeLastNumber() {

  var field1txt = document.getElementById('field1');

  if (field1txt.value.length == 1 || field1txt.value == '0' || field1txt.value == 'Syntax error') {
    field1txt.value = '0';
    document.getElementById('dec').disabled = false;
  } else {
    field1txt.value = field1txt.value.substring(0, field1txt.value.length - 1);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0px;
  background: black;
}

nav,
section,
article {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

#content {
  text-align: center;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: Red;
  color: green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  border: cornflowerblue solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 1px green;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px green;
}

input {
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  border: cornflowerblue solid 1px;
  text-align: right;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 1px green;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px blue;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div id='content'>
      <div id='content-app'>
        <input type='text' id='field1' readonly value='0' />
        <br /><br />
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n1'>1</button>
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n2'>2</button>
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n3'>3</button>
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n4'>4</button>
        <br /><br />
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n5'>5</button>
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n6'>6</button>
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n7'>7</button>
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n8'>8</button>
        <br /><br />
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n9'>9</button>
        <button onclick='writeNumber(this)' id='n0'>0</button>
        <button onclick='setDecimal(this,true)' id='dec'>.</button>
        <button onclick='setOperator(this)' id='sum'>+</button>
        <br /><br />
        <button onclick='setOperator(this)' id='sustract'>-</button>
        <button onclick='setOperator(this)' id='multi'>*</button>
        <button onclick='setOperator(this)' id='divide'>/</button>
        <button onclick='cleartxt()' id='C'>C</button>
        <br /><br />
        <button onclick='calculate()' id='calcular' style='width:190px'>=</button>
        <button onclick='removeLastNumber()' id='removeLast'>B</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br /><br />
  </article>
</section>
```